# Dynamic expression for generic orderby clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, dynamic-function

I need a little help for creating a generic method for fetching data from dbcontext and pass the 'orderby' clause as parameter.

So far a managed to do this:

```
public virtual Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<T, object>> orderby, bool asc = true)
{
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    if (orderby != null)
    {
        UnaryExpression UnExp = (UnaryExpression)orderby.Body;
        MemberExpression Exp = (MemberExpression)UnExp.Operand;
        var propInfo = (PropertyInfo)Exp.Member;

        //need new sort expression

        dbQuery = asc ? dbQuery.OrderBy(orderby) : dbQuery.OrderByDescending(orderby);
    }
    return dbQuery.ToListAsync<T>();
}
```

The part where I need help is how to convert

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> orderby
```

to

```
Expression<Func<T, "propInfo.PropertyType">> sortExpression
```

at runtime.I want to avoid sending extra type only for the sort expression.

```
Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderby
```

With current implementation there is no problem with string parameter
like

```
 var data = await GetListAsync(it => it.Name);
```

but if I try to sort by int parameter

```
var data = await GetListAsync(it => it.Id);
```

throws exception.Is that what I want achievable? Any help and advices are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Recommendation: put your solution as an answer, so that the question doesn't show up as "unanswered". You also may get rep from upvotes this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I made this solution:

```
public virtual Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderby)
{
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    if (orderby != null)
    {
        if (orderby != null)
        {
            dbQuery = orderby(dbQuery);
        }
    }
    return dbQuery.ToListAsync<T>();
}
```

and usage:

```
var data = await GetListAsync(q => q.OrderBy(it => it.Name))
```

I hope this help someone.